# How to rewrite if statment logic to the reactive approach in web security filter?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am sensibly new to project reactor and web flux, I want to rewrite my current traditional, blocking security filter to the reactive one, namely:

the current filter looks like this:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WhitelistingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private static final String SECURITY_PROPERTIES = "security.properties";
  private final Properties securityProperties = readConfigurationFile(SECURITY_PROPERTIES);
  private final String whitelistingEnabled = securityProperties.getProperty("whitelisting.enabled", FALSE.toString());

  private final RedisTemplate<String, Object> whitelistingRedisTemplate;
  private final AwsCognitoIdTokenProcessor awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor;

  public WhitelistingFilter(
      @Qualifier("whitelistingRedisTemplate")
          RedisTemplate<String, Object> whitelistingRedisTemplate,
      AwsCognitoIdTokenProcessor awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor) {
    this.whitelistingRedisTemplate = whitelistingRedisTemplate;
    this.awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor = awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request) {
    AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    return Stream.of(USER_LOGIN_URL, ADMIN_LOGIN_URL, SIGNUP_BY_ADMIN_URL, SIGNUP_URL, LOGOUT_URL)
            .anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath())) || whitelistingDisabled();
  }

  private boolean whitelistingDisabled() {
    return FALSE.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(whitelistingEnabled);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @NonNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) {
    try {
      Authentication authentication = awsCognitoIdTokenProcessor.getAuthentication(httpServletRequest);
      Optional<String> username = Optional.ofNullable(authentication.getName());
      if (username.isPresent() && usernameWhitelisted(username.get())) {
        log.info("User with username: {} is present in whitelisting", username.get());
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
      } else {
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        log.error("Username: {} not whitelisted or empty", username.orElse(""));
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Error occurred while checking user in redis whitelisting", e);
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
  }

  private boolean usernameWhitelisted(String username) {
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(whitelistingRedisTemplate.hasKey(WHITELISTING_PREFIX + username));
  }
}
```

New, incomplete, reactive approach class looks like this:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WhitelistingFilter implements WebFilter {

  private static final String SECURITY_PROPERTIES = "security.properties";
  public final List<String> whitelistedUrls =
      List.of(USER_LOGIN_URL, ADMIN_LOGIN_URL, SIGNUP_BY_ADMIN_URL, SIGNUP_URL, LOGOUT_URL);

  private final Properties securityProperties = readConfigurationFile(SECURITY_PROPERTIES);
  private final String whitelistingEnabled = securityProperties.getProperty("whitelisting.enabled", FALSE.toString());
  private final ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> whitelistingRedisTemplate;
  private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public WhitelistingFilter(
      @Qualifier("reactiveWhitelistingRedisTemplate")
          ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> whitelistingRedisTemplate,
      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.whitelistingRedisTemplate = whitelistingRedisTemplate;
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    Mono<String> username =
        ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .map(Authentication::getName);
    //logic here
    
  }

  private Mono<Boolean> whitelistingDisabled() {
    return Mono.just(FALSE.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(whitelistingEnabled));
  }

  private Mono<Boolean> usernameWhitelisted(Mono<String> username) {
    return whitelistingRedisTemplate.hasKey(WHITELISTING_PREFIX + username);
  }
}
```

I changed the `usernameWhitelisted()` and `whitelistingDisabled()` methods to return Mono's but I cannot figure out how to verify if the username is whitelisted and whitelisting enabled in reactive approach. I tried to do sth

```
username.flatMap(u -> {
  if(two conditions here) 
})
```

but with this approach, I am providing Mono to the if statment which is contradictory with Java semantic. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to rewrite the code and make it works in a reactive approach.

Answer (score 0):

Having a reactive stream or pipe doesn't mean that everything needs to be reactive, you can just leave the mono out of the boolean operators

As you return a Mono of type void and since you need (?) logging, I guess you could just throw a custom exception in here as well and catch it on top op the stream/pipe by using the `doOnError` and in there check for the exception type and have according logic (pass a msg to the exception should you need one)

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .map(Authentication::getName)
            .doOnNext(this::doBla)

public void doBla(String username) {
   if (!whitelistingDisabled() || !usernameWhitelisted(username)) {
      throw new TypeException(ms);
  }
}
```

FYI doOnNext is only  being executed if you reach that part, its kind of like a peek in a java stream. 
The doOnError its functionality could also be extracted, a stream is easier to read to keep it simple and not add too much into it

```
myStream
     ....otherOperators
     .filter(bla)
     ...
     .doOnError(e -> {
        if ( e instanceOf TypeException) {
           // do stuff 
        }
     }
```